# data structure to eliminate multiple hashtables in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-structures

i am developing an application in which i add controls during runtime and to keep track of these controls i am maintaing separate hashtables so that it will be easy for me to do what ever i want with them later. But I am having around 6 hashtables and maintaining these is a little complex. So i was wondering whether i can have all these controls in to one data structure but it should be easy for me to identify them just like i do in hashtable. Basically what i want is an extended version of hashtable where i can add  multiple values to one key. For example what i have now is

```
 hashtable addButtons = new hashtable();
 hashtable remButtons = new hashtable();

 addButtons.add(name,b);
 remButtons.add(name,r);
```

Now it would be cool if i can do something like

```
addButtons.add(name=>(b,r,etc,etc));
```

and then get any of it just like in hashtable like

```
addButtons[name][1]
```

Can any one tell me if something like this is possible in c#.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is this not doable with a `Dictionary<string, List<control>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a class representing the 6 things...

```
public class SomeType { // RENAME ME
    public int AddButton {get;set;}
    public string RemoveButton {get;set;}
    public DateTime Some {get;set;}
    public float Other {get;set;}
    public decimal Names {get;set;}
    public bool Here {get;set;}
} // ^^ names and types above just made up; FIX ME!
```

and a `Dictionary<string,SomeType>` - then you can:

```
yourField.Add(name, new SomeType { AddButton = ..., ..., Here = ... });
```

and

```
var remButton = yourField[name].RemoveButton;
```

Answer (score 3):

How about `Dictionary<String, List<?>>` ?

Combined with something like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
     public static void AddItemsWithName<T>(this Dictionary<String, List<T>> this, string name, params T[] items)
     {
           // ...
     }
}
```

Would give you something very close to the syntax you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understood your question correctly. Something like this?

```
var controlsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Control>>();

var b1 = new Button();
var b2 = new Button();

controlsDictionary["AddButtons"] = new List<Control> { b1, b2 };

var firstButton = controlsDictionary["AddButtons"][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a Dictionary of Dictionaries, something like:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Control>>();

//Create new sub dictionary
d.Add("name1", new Dictionary<string, Control>());

//Add control
d["name1"].Add("btnOne", btnOne);

//Retrieve control
var ctrl = d["name1"]["btnOne"];
```